# How to set HTTP-Header when streaming an Audio file?

Tags: angular, rxjs, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I was following the tutoriel "[Building an Audio Player app with Angular and RxJS](https://auth0.com/blog/building-an-audio-player-app-with-angular-and-rxjs/)" and managed to get the audio player working.

However, in order to load the audio from my server, I need to set the [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header. Is there a way to do this? I am already using a `HttpInterceptor` for this for all other requests but it seems that the interceptor is bypassed as I load the audio file.

The code below is how the audio gets loaded and played:

```js
private audioObj = new Audio();

// ...

private streamObservable(url: string): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    // Play audio
    this.audioObj.src = url;
    this.audioObj.load();
    this.audioObj.play().then();

    const handler = (event: Event) => {
      this.updateStateEvents(event);
      observer.next(event);
    };

    this.addEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);

    return () => {
      // Stop Playing
      this.audioObj.pause();
      this.audioObj.currentTime = 0;
      // remove event listeners
      this.removeEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);
      // reset state
      this.resetState();
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you want it by streaming specifically?

Comment: @RafiHenig Ideally I'd like to _really_ stream the audio from my server to the client such that I never have to download the entire file but it seems that his would be a much more challenging task. For now I'd be happy to just load the file content from the server and play ("stream") it on the client side. Speaking of.. is it possible to transform the audio data before it actually gets played via output device? That would be handy in order to regulate loudness and/or other effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Authorization header to the audio URL as a URL parameter, along with a custom authentication handler on the server.

You may also (if streaming is not essential) use Angular HTTPClient to download the audio file as a Blob:

```js
private playObservable(url: string): Observable<any> {    
  this.http.get<Blob>(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
    .pipe(
      map(blob => window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)),
      switchMap(url => {
        return new Observable(observer => {
          // Play audio
          this.audioObj.src = url;
          this.audioObj.load();
          this.audioObj.play().then();

          const handler = (event: Event) => {
            this.updateStateEvents(event);
            observer.next(event);
          };

          this.addEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);

          return () => {
            // Stop Playing
            this.audioObj.pause();
            this.audioObj.currentTime = 0;
            // remove event listeners
            this.removeEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, handler);
            // reset state
            this.resetState();

            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
          };

        })
      })
    )
```

Comment: I do realize now why you asked about whether I want it "_by streaming_". I guess that was a misunderstanding. You solution downloads the entire file first and after that it plays the file. This is unfortunately not a solution in my case because the user would have to wait too long until the audio plays.

Comment: I thought you said  "For now I'd be happy to just load the file content from the server and play ("stream") it on the client side."

Comment: Yes, I think that's because "stream" is a bit ambiguous here. What I meant was that I don't need a more sophisticated mechanism like spotify/audible where you can jump to any arbitrary position right away. I think what they do is basically request specific chunks of an audio and sends only those bytes to the client. That's another level - but I need the audio to (at least) play "right away" after clicking the play button. Some files can be 30MB plus and the waiting time would just be too long :/ Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @StefanFalk I have the same requirement. When I specify an Authorization header, my audio files are downloaded completely before the files are played. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Simon I don't think so but I discovered [`shaka-player`](https://github.com/google/shaka-player) lately. Haven't used it yet and I don't know if I will but you might want to take a look at it.

Comment: In the end we implemented it without Authorization Header via signedUrls...